# Let [a,b]$\subseteq \Bbb R$ be a closed bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let [a,b]$\subseteq \Bbb R$ be a closed bounded interval, and let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be a function.
Suppose that f is continuous.
Prove that there is some $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$.
The number c is called a fixed point of $f$.

---

What I have so far:
Using the Intermediate Value Theorem,
Suppose that c is strictly between f(a) and f(b).  Assume that $f(a) < c < f(b)$.
Let $S=\{ x\in [a,b] \big\rvert f(x)<c \}$, then $S\subseteq [a,b]$.
Let $c=lubS$.
... *Proof of $f(c)=c$ by showing $f(c)\geq c$ and $f(c)\leq c$* ...
Because $S\neq \emptyset$ , then $f(S) \neq \emptyset $.  From the definition of S, $f(S)$ is bounded above by c.
$f(lubS)\leq lub f(S)$, so $f(c)\leq lubf(S)$.  Because c is an upper bound of $f(S)$, it follows that $lubf(S)\leq c$, and thus $f(c)\leq c$
Because $f(c) \leq c \leq f(b)$, we can see that $c\neq b$, so $c<b$. It follows that the interval (c,b] is non-degenerate.
Let B=(c,b].  Then $f(B)\neq \emptyset $ and $c=glbB$.  Since $c=lubS$, it follows that $B\subseteq [a,b]-S$, so $f(x) \geq c$ for all $x\in B$.
Therefore, $f(B)$ is bounded below by c.
So, $f(glbB)\geq glbf(B)$. Which means that $f(c)\geq glbf(B)$.  Because c is a lower bound of $f(B)$, it follows that $glbf(B)\geq c$.  So $f(c)\geq c$.
... So $f(c)=c$...
Finally, since $c\neq f(a)$ and $c\neq f(b)$, then $c\neq a$ and $c\neq b$, so $c\in (a,b)$

Comment: Please, improve the readability of the question.

Comment: Note that $lub$ is usually called supremum and $glb$ infimum. The first step is questionable to wrong, since you use $c$ to define  $S$ and that to define $c$ and then treat both as the same. This is quite circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the things in a very complicated fashion.

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$, which is continuous. Then $g(a)=f(a)-a\ge 0$, whereas $g(b)=f(b)-b\le 0$.

If $g(a)=0$, we are done; if $g(b)=0$, we are done.

If $g(a)>0$ and $g(b)<0$, …

Note that in general you can't prove that $c\in(a,b)$. Consider, for instance, $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$, $f(x)=x/2$. Then $f(x)=x$ only for $x=0$.

Comment: I grafted the problem onto the proof of the IVT in my book, it seemed to make sense, but, as you mentioned, was long-winded.

Comment: @frierfly Yes, you're basically reproving the IVT and you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $f(x)$ crosses $g(x) = \frac{b}{a}(x-a) + a$. Since $f(a) \ge g(a), f(b) \le g(b)$ and since both $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are continuous, they cross somewhere, namely (at least) at $x = c$.

Comment: $g(b)=b^2/a-b+a$ is not a very nice value. What you mean is $g(x)=x$ with $g(a)=a\le f(a)$ and $g(b)=b\ge f(b)$.